# Adding in SQL, adding Income, Expenses, Sorting by Name

Tags: php, sql, database, sum, pivot

would like to ask for help if there is a way to do this?
any suggestion please thank you.

I have this table on my database for example

[image: computation table]

And want to have a result like this one

[image: results]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, would you like to show your sql query?

Comment: You have the data and you know what you want but for others an image doesn't really help. Please post the data and expected result in the original question itself. And if you provide table structure and data in insertion format would be very much helpful.

Comment: Thank you, have change the question hope this works out.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(case when money_type = 'Income' then amount else 0 end) total_income,
    sum(case when money_type = 'Expenses' then amount else 0 end) total_expenses,
    ...
from mytable
```